# Output of saved .R files in r

Tags: r

I want to save my code in R. I did:

```
save(Data,file="Code_Data.R")
```

When I open the file in R again, the code looks like hieroglyphics.

How can I save the code in a way, that I can read the code in an editor or RStudio again?

Comment: It sounds like you saved an object in your workspace called `Data` into the Code_Data.R file. If you're using RStudio, you should be typing your code into the Source pane (top left, above the Console pane). Ctrl-S when you wish to save the code you typed in there. If the Source pane is not visible, go to File -> New File -> R Script & it will open.

Answer (score 2):

[`save`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/save) outputs a binary copy of the objects you tell it to save, not R code.  Because you are naming this file with a ".R" extension, RStudio is blindly trying to open this binary file as R code, and you are seeing the results of that mess.

Technically, the R language doesn't care what the extension of the file is.  As long as *you* know that the file contains, you can load it back in with the command `load("Code_Data.R")`.  However, if you want to get RStudio to recognize that this is actually a file containing binary data and not R code, try saving the file with the canonical ".RData" extension:

```
save(Data, file="Code_Data.RData")
```

Using the ".RData" extension will also help you and other programmers who look at your code avoid this confusion in the future.